# Regression Model Comparrison

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, regression

I'm looking for metrics to compare various regressions models (e.g. SVM, Decision Tree, Neural Network etc), to decide the merits of each for solving a specific problem.

For my problem I have just over 80,000 training samples with 12 variables, all of which are independent and identically distributed.

I've done most of my research into neural networks but I'm drawing a blank when trying to compare them against other models.

Any input (including reading suggestions) would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can compare regression models by calculating the *mean squared error* for each model over a test set. The best model will simply be the one with the least error.

Sadly, there ist nothing like roc curves for regression models. Except your output is a binary variable like with logistic regression.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way of assessing a models suitability prior to actually training and testing it? i.e. inherent benefits/drawbacks for each?

Comment: Mhh, that's quite hard to tell. A neural net theoretically can approximate any function, an SVM needs a kernel function to transform data into an higher dimensional feature space....and so ...I'd go the way by trying out one or the other.